# Need to see what is different text between two cells

Tags: vba, excel-formula

In Excel I have

- `Column A` (Address: example `POBOX1234ATLANTAGA30374`)
- `Column B` (Address: example `POBOX2345ATLANTAGA30384`)

I need to make a `Column C` that shows the difference between the two.

For example, highlight `1234` and `7` as a different font color. I'm open for any ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Only substitutions (no deletions or inserts)?

Comment: This is positional differences? What happens if column B was 1POBOX1234ATLANTAGA30374 ?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub CompareCells(c1 As Range, c2 As Range)
    Dim p As Long
    If c1.Cells.Count + c2.Cells.Count <> 2 Then _
        MsgBox "Must specify two single cells.": Exit Sub
    For p = 1 To IIf(Len(c2) < Len(c1), Len(c2), Len(c1))
        If Mid(c1, p, 1) <> Mid(c2, p, 1) Then c2.Characters(p, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
    Next p
End Sub
```

If your values are in cells **A1** and **A2**, you could use it like this:

```
CompareCells [a1], [a2]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Safety net of Trim at start to ensure no white space throwing of comparison?

Comment: @RDrago What is the problem?  (Can you clarify why it doesn't work?)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CompareInColor()

ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub CompareInColorFlip()

ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value

For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value)
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This compares `A1` and `B1` only... Loop through your rows if you have many of them. Also, I assumed that the length of `A1` and `A2` is the same, otherwise an out-of-range index error may evolve.

Comment: Both of these procedures appear to just change the text.  I had _ABCD_ in `A1` and _ACBD_ in `C1`.  The result was _ABCD_ coloured red in `C1`.  Same result in the second procedure.  If that's the result you're after you could just compare `A1` to `C1` and if they're different copy `A1` to `C1` and colour red.